# Gatsby JS url path is not updating correctly

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm using Gatsby JS and for some reason, the url for the new page is being added to the end of the current url. I'll try to explain. Here is a live example:

On this page: `https://nyxo.app/week/understanding-your-sleep` is a list of lessons for a sleep coaching week. When the user clicks a lesson, the url should become `https://nyxo.app/lesson/lesson-name`.

Currently, this is happening instead: `https://nyxo.app/week/understanding-your-sleep/lesson/lesson-name.` and it's resulting in a 404.

Here is the `gatsby-node.js` file, showing how the templates are created.

```
// gatsby-node.js

  weeks.forEach((week: Week) => {
    createPage({
      path: `week/${week.node.slug}`,
      component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/week.tsx`),
      context: {
        slug: week.node.slug,
        locale: "en-US",
      },
    })
  })

lessons.forEach((lesson: Lesson) => {
    createPage({
      path: `lesson/${lesson.node.slug}`,
      component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/lesson.tsx`),
      context: {
        slug: lesson.node.slug,
      },
    })
  })
```

Here is the template file for the Weeks page. You can see the path doesn't include the week and the week name, on top of the lesson and lesson name.

```
// week.tsx template

{week.lessons.map((lesson: any) => (
     <LessonCard
      authors={[{ name: "testi", fixed: null }]}
      key={lesson.slug}
      path={`lesson/${lesson.slug}`} // the path to the lesson file
      excerpt={""}
      name={lesson.lessonName}
      readingTime={lesson.lessonContent.fields.readingTime.text}
     />
))}
```

This has just started and I don't know why, but I wanted to see if anyone else has experienced this and how they overcame it. This problem seems to be limited to templates. I appreciate any help/advice.
✌️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your paths and slugs must start with a slash (`/`), like:

```
 <LessonCard
  authors={[{ name: "testi", fixed: null }]}
  key={lesson.slug}
  path={`/lesson/${lesson.slug}`} // the path to the lesson file
  excerpt={""}
  name={lesson.lessonName}
  readingTime={lesson.lessonContent.fields.readingTime.text}
 />
```

If you don't start your string path with a slash it will concatenate as a relative path.

In addition, to avoid possibles cohesion issues, in the same way, your `createPage` function must contain slashed paths like:

```
  path: `/lesson/${lesson.node.slug}`,
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!!